# How to open up 700mb file

Tags: software-recommendation

What text editor for Linux can open up 700mb text file for editing? Please advice, Kate & Jedit does not work out

Comment: Disable `vim`'s more advanced stuff (syntax highlighting, folding) and then use it: http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/149/how-can-i-open-very-large-files-with-good-performance

Answer (score 2):

[GNU Emacs](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsFileSizeLimit).

> Old versions (i.e., anything before 19.29) of GNU Emacs had problems editing files larger than 8 megabytes. As of version 19.29, the maximum buffer size is at least 2^27-1, or 134,217,727 bytes. On a 64bit system, the limit is pushed to 2^59-1 which is almost a million Terabytes.

[Vim](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/vi_diff.html#limits)

> Maximum file size 2147483647 bytes (2 Gbyte) when a long integer is 32 bits. Much more for 64 bit longs. Also limited by available disk space for the |swap-file|.